# How to get count of all child elements that matches an expression

Tags: mongodb

Assume the following MongoDB documents:

```
{
  "name": "cat 1",
  "desc": "cat 1 desc",
  articles: [] 
},
{
  "name": "cat 2",
  "desc": "cat 2 desc",
  "parent": "cat 1",
  articles: [
    {
      "name": "art 1"
    },
    {
      "name": "art 2"
    }
  ] 
}
```

Now, I would like to query the database, for finding a product where the name contains "art" and category is "cat 1".

I would like to have the amount of products under each category that fits, while keeping the hierarchy, this does mean that I would like to receive something like this:

```
{
  "name": "cat 1",
  "count": 2
}
```

Is this possible with the Aggregation framework?
If now, how would I structure my database then to support my request?

Kind regards

Comment: what is mean category is "cat 1" ?

Comment: It's used for hierarchical data storage.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why is your category field but i take this is name field.

Query :

```
db.coll.aggregate([ 
    { $match : {"articles.name" : {$regex : ".*art.*"}, "name":"cat 2"} },              
    { $unwind:'$articles'}, 
    { $group: {
        _id : {
             name: "$articles.name",
             category:"$name"
        }, 
        count : { $sum : 1 } 
    }} 
])
```

Comment: This is not what I require, this would given me all documents where articles contains art and name is cat 1, thus I will only find cat 2 where I also need to find cat 1 because cat 1 is a parent of cat 2 and I need the count of the total articles then.

Comment: Not quite, I'm sorry, you're grouping on articles name which seems ok, but in the response I also need to category. So I need to have category 1 contains x items, category 2 contains x items... Now I'm only retrieing how many times an article with a given name is found, not how many articles are found per category.

Comment: Almost. Sorry to dissapoint you but the issue I'm having right now is:
When I have 2 articles with the same name and the same category, it's count as one and should be count as 2. This is due to the fact to you group on classification name and article name.